# Deep Elasticsearch wildcard query for given time range and with AND operator

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I managed to build query that

- matches all exact values in given time range
- supports `and` operator.

Now I want to extend the query to support **partial matching** but I struggle to do that. Any advice would be appreciated.

**Mapping**

```
"event": {
    "properties": {
        "alarmId": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "startTimestamp": {
            "type": "long"
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

**Current query**

```
{
    "bool": {
        "must":[
            {"range": {"endTimestamp": {"gte": ?0}}},
            {"range": {"startTimestamp": {"lte": ?1}}}
        ],
        "should": [
            {"match": {"_all": {"query": "?2", "zero_terms_query": "all", "operator": "and"}}}
        ],
        "minimum_should_match" : 1
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37315275/elasticsearch-search-for-parts-of-words

Comment: @Val Interesting, It might work, but why there are dots in the query? `'*'.$val.'*`

Comment: That's the string concatenation operator in PHP :) In your case that doesn't apply, simply use `"whatever*"`

Comment: @Val Thanks, I don't know PHP. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer** (thanks to [Val](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4604579/val))

```
{
    "bool": {
        "must":[
            {"range": {"endTimestamp": {"gte": ?0}}},
            {"range": {"startTimestamp": {"lte": ?1}}}
        ],
        "should": [
            {"query_string": {"query": "?2"}}"
        ],
        "minimum_should_match" : 1
    }
}
```

Now query supports [grouping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_grouping), [wildcards](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_wildcards) and [more](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html).